# Files that are not changed are triggering nodemon restarts

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I use handlebars and nodemon on Windows. I've noticed (when using the `debug` argument for nodemon), hbs files - even when they aren't being edited - trigger a nodemon change.

Are the files actually changing? Why are they changing if I'm not editing them?

```
[11:22:46] [nodemon] files triggering change check: ..\forgot-sent.hbs
[11:22:46] [nodemon] matched rule: C:\Users\me\Documents\myapp\views/**/*
[11:22:46] [nodemon] changes after filters (before/after): 1/1
[11:22:46] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[11:22:46] [nodemon] views\forgot-sent.hbs
```

**How can I make nodemon refresh when files are changed, and not refresh when files are not changed?**

**Edit**: looks like a bug on nodemon/Windows, see https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1208

Comment: Try running with `nodemon -L`

Comment: Thanks @beingsrv! Alas I've done some research and found a bunch of other Windows users having the same problem - opens causing nodemon to restart - I've added a link to the bug above.

Comment: happens to me in docker container in linux too.
did you found the solution? `-L` is not helping

Comment: @Kostanos See my new answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a [bug in nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1208) (or more specifically, chokidar, a dependency of nodemon)

[It was fixed on Feb 8 2019](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/commit/fb0c078013c4b50a7e47f415aee9cf9168fc16db)

Upgrade to [the latest nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) to get the fix.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem using nodemon v 2.0.20

Answer (score -1):

add filenames extension after command `nodemon` as...

`nodemon -e 'js|handlebars|hbs|html'`

-e specifies extensions to be tracked

You can add different filetypes if you use other template engines as `'js|ejs|hbs'`.

Comment: This isn't an answer to this question.